# Update firebase database with time-based key on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase and iOS to keep a time series of an integer value over the last 24 hours. I have tried using both the `.updateChildValues()` and `.setValue()` from the docs, but haven't yet figured out how to keep firebase from overwriting every child value, not just the child value with the same key.

```
func writeStepsPost(withUserID userID: String, steps: NSNumber) {
    let timeStamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber
    let post_user: NSString = userID as NSString
    let value: NSNumber = steps

    let post = ["uid": post_user,
                "steps": value,
                "lastUpdate":timeStamp]
    let childUpdates = ["/posts-steps-user/\(userID)/": post]
    ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
    let currentHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
    let hourlyPost = ["steps":value]
    let dailyUpdates = ["/posts-steps-user/\(userID)/pastDay/\(currentHour):00/": hourlyPost]
    print("posting hourly steps update")
    ref.updateChildValues(dailyUpdates)
```

When the time changes from 10 to 11, the node for `'10:00':123` is replaced by `'11:00':243`, when I need to add a node for `11` while leaving `10` in place until the next day. I suspect that since the function is pushing two updates, the first update replaces the existing node.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using this code and was getting a node like `userID/pastDay/10:00:123` and the next hour, I get `userID/pastDay/11:00:234`.  It didn't overwrite the first, but created a new one.  How are you defining `value` in your `timedRef.setValue(value)` command?  I don't understand how you are getting `10:123` and not `10:00:(some-value)` as you literally have :00 in your timedRef path.

Comment: @ParrettApps I misspoke in the OP, I've edited it to be more clear.

Comment: @ParrettApps Firebase appears to be replacing the `pastDay` node, which is deleting all of its children.

Answer (score 0):

Given a single key path like `/posts-steps-user/\(userID)/`, `updateChildValues` only updates data at the first child level, and any data passed in beyond the first child level is a treated as a `setValue` operation. Multi-path behavior allows longer paths to be used without overwriting data.  It is documented very well in this [Firebase Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-update).

I've tested with the following adjustment to your code where I define multiple paths for your first `updateChildValues` so it won't overwrite your `pastDay` and it is working properly.

```
let childUpdatePath = "/posts-steps-user/\(userID)/"
ref.updateChildValues([
            "\(childUpdatePath)/uid": post_user,
            "\(childUpdatePath)/steps": value,
            "\(childUpdatePath)/lastUpdate": timeStamp
            ])
let currentHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
let hourlyPost = ["steps":value]
let dailyUpdates = ["/posts-steps-user/\(userID)/pastDay/\(currentHour):00/": hourlyPost]
ref.updateChildValues(dailyUpdates)
```

Comment: It's updating a parent node earlier in the same function. I suspect this is part of the problem. I'll add that code to the OP.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer based on the additional code you've provided.